# Use powershell to extract PreShared Key (PSK) for L2TPIPsecAuth or change RememberCredential from FALSE to TRUE

Tags: windows-10, vpn, powershell

I am tired of typing my VPN creds on my work laptop.  I need to use a new VPN client that will remember my username & password or get the Win 10 VPN client to remember them.

The problem is that **I don't have the PSK** for this connection that's on my laptop.  **How do I extract it?**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-VpnConnection -AllUserConnection

Name                  : VPN_2
ServerAddress         : vpn.company_name.ca
AllUserConnection     : True
Guid                  : {Long-alpha-number-string-here-47BF45055ABC}
TunnelType            : L2tp
AuthenticationMethod  : {MsChapv2}
EncryptionLevel       : Optional
L2tpIPsecAuth         : Psk
UseWinlogonCredential : False
EapConfigXmlStream    :
ConnectionStatus      : Disconnected
RememberCredential    : False
SplitTunneling        : False
DnsSuffix             :
IdleDisconnectSeconds : 0
```

Or how do I get win 10 VPN client to remember creds?  I have admin access to the laptop.  I don't know what registry settings are in place to tell it to annoy me every time I use it though!

As for checking the PBK, I have gone to: C:\Users\users_name\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk_hiddenPbk

and the PreSharedKey is blank.

I see that the key is stored in `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections > right-click properties of VPN > Security > advanced settings`  but I can't see it (just *****).

Comment: When the connection is for All Users, the pbk is in `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk` instead of `%appdata%`

Comment: @user19702 Thanks, I just checked but the PreSharedKey is also blank in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to how to change RememberCredential to TRUE.

`Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections > right-click properties of VPN > Options > Check 'Remember my Credentials'`

Note: you must have admin access to get into the properties.